# Java Regex NPE On Matcher.Find()

Tags: java, regex, nullpointerexception

I'm going insane trying to figure out why this doesn't work.

I've got a changelog file where I want to consume contents, and parse out version numbers. I have an existing regex that works that I've used as a baseline for the the new regex to just strip version numbers and can see that it works. However, when I attempt to iterate through the new Matcher results using .find() method to just get the version numbers, I'm getting a Null Pointer Exception and no results are found.

Is there an issue with the regex, or the way it's being compiled, or something else?

FWIW, the regex pattern does exactly what I want when I try it on a few online regex editors (Java based).

Here's what I'm running.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HelloWorld{

    public static final String changelog="## Current Version"+
            "\n\n"+
            "- None"+
            "\n\n"+
            "## 5.18.72 (2020-01-17)"+
            "\n\n"+
            "- #### [US12345]"+
            "\n\n"+
            "## 5.18.71 (2020-01-15)"+
            "\n\n"+
            "- #### [US123456]"+
            "\n\n"+
            "## 5.18.70 (2020-01-09)";

    private static final String RAW_CHANGELOG_PATTERN = "(?ms)(##[\\w\\s\\-]*.%s.*\n\n.*)(\n\n##[\\w\\s\\-]*.%s)";
    private static final String RAW_CHANGELOG_VERSION_PATTERN="(?ms)(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})";

     public static void main(String []args){


        System.out.println(extractKnownVersions(changelog));

        System.out.println("Next\n");

        System.out.println(extractVersions(changelog.toString()));
     }

    private static String extractKnownVersions(String changelog){
        String patternString = String.format(RAW_CHANGELOG_PATTERN,"5.18.72","5.18.70");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(changelog);
        String result = null;
        if (matcher.find()) {
            result = matcher.group();
        } else {
            System.out.println("No diff found between versions 5.18.72 and 5.18.70 Check that both versions exist in Changelog.");
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static List<String> extractVersions(String changelog) {
        // TODO: Fix the regex so that it actually grabs what we want
        String patternString = RAW_CHANGELOG_VERSION_PATTERN;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(changelog);

        List<String> result = null;
        int count = 0;

        try {
            while (matcher.find()) {
                result.add(matcher.group());
                System.out.println("result: " + result.get(count));
                count++;
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            System.out.println("NPE: Could not extract versions from Changelog");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception extracting versions from Changelog");
        }

        System.out.println("match count:" + count);
        return result;
    }
}
```

And here's the output on SOP -- notice the original regex `RAW_CHANGELOG_PATTERN` works and produces the output I'm expecting (everything between the two version numbers), but the second method `extractVersions` which uses the new regex `RAW_CHANGELOG_VERSION_PATTERN` is throwing the NPE.

```
## 5.18.72 (2020-01-17)

- #### [US12345]

## 5.18.71 (2020-01-15)

- #### [US123456]

## 5.18.70
Next

NPE: Could not extract versions from Changelog
match count:0
null
```

I'm hoping this is something silly syntax wise that I'm missing?

Comment: It would have been easier to debug this if you did not swallow your stacktraces, and instead printed them out so you can see what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your NPE is from uninitialized List:

```
List<String> result = null;
```

Changed to

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

result: 5.18.72
result: 5.18.71
result: 5.18.70
match count:3
[5.18.72, 5.18.71, 5.18.70]
```

Comment: Nailed it - thanks so much for a quick response!